# Xamarin.Forms ListView does not highlight selected item?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios13

Trying to ramp up a new project on Xamarin.Forms, and on iOS 13 no highlight is being shown on my ListViews. Using Visual Studio for Mac's out-of-the-box "Blank Forms App" solution, I changed the contents on MainPage.xaml to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="ListViewTest.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                    <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                    <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                    <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

When "monotouch" is selected, the view looks like the image attached below, both in the simulator and on the device. I would have expected a gray selection bar on the "monotouch" row, but instead it only modified the row borders.

This is on Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.908675 (the latest as of this date). I tried rolling back to Forms 4.0 and 3.6 and saw the same results on both, which makes it seem like something new in iOS 13?

I tried searching for someone else having the issue, but only found articles on changing or hiding the highlight color; I'm just looking to match the system behavior.

Has anyone else bumped into this? Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: iOS 13 screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried with iOS 12 simulator?

Comment: This is a known issue with Xam.Forms and iOS 13 (due to a change ioS made to the native UITableView) and a fix was merged 11 hours ago, so the fix should be in the next release. See: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7850

Comment: Thank you! That issue hadn't yet been opened when I first encountered it; I should have thought to search again before posting. Could you repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new release fixed this bug

> Wednesday, October 30, 2019 - Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.947036 (4.3.0
>   Service Release 1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.3/4.3.0-sr1